# Is it possible to use (or include) node.js framework in a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I don't want to create a chrome extension ONLY using node.js.

I know chrome extensions use HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

But I want to make a chat application as a chrome extension. I found that using MEAN stack along with socket.io for a chat application is the latest way and is efficient.

1) So, I'm wondering if it is possible to integrate or link my node application as a Google chrome extension?

2) If not possible, does plain JavaScript or any other library serve the same purpose? Can I use socket.io with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a chat application you would need a server, which should not be in the browser. Chat clients may be built using the current HTML + CSS + JS extensions API, you do not need Node.JS for creating them.

Yes, you can use Socket.io with the Google Chrome extensions, you just have to include the Socket.io client-side script in you extension

Comment: Thanks @micnic for the answer. Any idea on how to include Socket.io in client side JavaScript. Can I just copy the library and link it like we do for  jQuery?

Comment: yes, you can include it as a simple script, I recommend you to use the location from your server location like `http://serverhost/socket.io/socket.io.js` so you do not need to update your extension if you update the socket.io version

Answer (score 1):

Node.js does not run natively within Chrome extensions or Chrome apps, but you can definitely write a Chrome extension chat app using node.js and socket.io.

To do so, have your extension use a [Page Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction). Your popup.html would be an JavaScript app (for example, using AngularJS), and it would talk to a node.js backend (for example, using socket.io lib).

Comment: Thanks @orcaman for the answer. But, I'll be using a button action. The problem which I have is how to include the socket.io or node.js in chrome extensions? Normally, I used npm and downloaded socket.io but now how do I include this with the extension? Can I copy the socket.io library or include it just like we do with jQuery?